# Can this be anything other than a resistor?

Tags: resistors

I have been messing with an old valve amp and have replaced the filter caps and a couple of resistors that were a little out of tolerance. The component in the picture does not look the same as any of the others and, if it is a resistor, seems to be out of tolerance by a couple of orders of magnitude (my reading is 1.2M, whereas the colour bands seem to indicate 95R). The others were only a few percent out. I just wanted to check it really was a resistor before replacing it...

[image: Old resistor... I think...]

Thanks!

Comment: That's silver, not grey.

Comment: is it a diode perhaps?

Comment: I get the feeling it's not a resistor. It just doesn't feel right to me. Could be a diode, or maybe a capacitor. There don't seem to be enough bands though for either resistor or capacitor, so maybe a diode of some form?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, definitely silver. I had understood from a table I found that silver was 9 and black was not used as the first stripe, so had been reading it from the silver end. Reading from the other end the value would be 0.05R, giving me an even bigger discrepancy.

Comment: yeah, do a diode test on it

Comment: What other functions does your meter have? Can you measure capacitance, forward voltage drop, or inductance? Last one is a long shot...

Comment: Which table was that?

Comment: Can't measure capacitance or inductance. Can measure forward voltage drop but I have the same resistance both ways - doesn't this rule out a diode?

Comment: The table is at http://www.philipstorr.id.au/radio/technical/BTS_Resistors.pdf

Comment: long shot as to why a diode test doesnt work, is it's a bi-directional zener clamp!? lol

Comment: mmm no idea what that is but it's a pretty low tech piece of kit so sounds unlikely...

Comment: Looks like it's connected across the input socket. High value resistor there is to provide a path to ground for the input capacitor to charge, so you don't get a huge click when you plug a guitar in with the volume up - so yeah, resistor, nothing exotic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a 1 M ohm carbon composition resistor. Different manufacturers used different ways of showing the value and the Brown of the body indicates a 1 in this example I believe. The black at the end then indicates a 0. This is then followed by 5 zeros due to the green band.

If I remember correctly silver indicates tolerance but I'm unsure about this - I think it's either 5 or 10%.

Comment: Yup 10%. Gold is 5% and none is 20%. 1M would be about right for a grid resistor IIRC.

Comment: Old (OLD old) resistors were marked "body, tip & spot" - brown, black, green would be right for 1 Mohm - this seems to have replaced the "spot" with a ring so probably dates from about 1960.